# Instance Variables in js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, erb

From what I have read in several other questions, my instance variables defined in my controller should be accessible in my `js.erb` file.  They aren't.  Note: I'm not trying to render a partial - just access the variable's (string) content, which I will then apply to a div.

If not nil, my variables show up as `true` and crash on gsub if I use `j` (javascript escape) on them, in some cases - but that is a close to being able to differentiate between when they are nil and existing in the `js.erb` file.  When they exist, I get `an empty string` returned in firebug-console on a `console.log()`.

For example:

**Controller Code**

```
def myCntlMethod
   @myvar = "MyVarTest"
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
end
```

**js.erb code:**

```
console.log('<% @myvar %>');
```

Result in Firebug:

> (an empty string)

Also tried

```
console.log('<% j @myvar %>');
```

same result in this case - crashes if I do an inspect or present?  And ...

```
console.log('<% j myvar %>');
```

rails crashes and tells me the variable does not exist, as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason of absence the evaluated text in result *HTML* is forgotten equal sign in the evaluation operator. In order to *ERB* text processor inserted a value of a ruby code make sure that you have used the following form:

```
<%= @myvar %>
```

instead of:

```
<% @myvar %>
```

Second case form is need only ruby code execution inside the ERB template, not for a result insertion:

```
<% @myvars.each do| myvar | -%>
  <p></p>
<% end %>
```

In the similar causes always at first check the equal sign in evaluation operators.

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log('<%= @myvar %>');
```